# I'm getting DropdownButton Error, I'm looking for a way to solve it

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pull data to dropdown with api. Everything is going very well until it comes to dropdown. But when it comes to dropdown, I get an error like this.

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 892 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)
```

I am getting this error when I try to list these returned records. I'm new to Flutter and I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

Dropdown
`

```
  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: _mystate,
                          iconSize: 30,
                          icon: (null),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                          hint: Text("Lütfen Seçim Yapınız"),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _mystate=newValue.toString();
                             sevkikayatListesi();
                             print(_mystate);
                            });
                          },
                          items: _items.map((item) {
                            return  DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(item.CARIISIM.toString()),
                              value: item.YUKLEMENO,
                               );
                          })?.toList()??
                          [],
                        )
```

Api

```
  sevkikayatListesi() async {

    final response = await Dio().get('http://192.168.0.21/api/values/Degerler');
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      final _datas = response.data;
      if (_datas is List) {
        setState(() {
          _items = _datas.map((e) => PaletToplamaGrid.fromJson(e)).toList();
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Bunlarda değişkenlerim:

```
  List<PaletToplamaGrid> _items = [];
  String _mystate = "";
```

Comment: _mystate should having initial value not blank

Comment: I entered _myState value but error persists

Comment: show your full code

Answer (score 1):

Initial value should be `null` or the item should be available in the list.

```
String? _mystate;
```